# WSO2 API Manager 1.6.0 Published API does not show up in the store

Tags: configuration, wso2, config, wso2-api-manager

I have a distributed Publisher (port 9446) and Store (port 9447).  I'm starting them with the -Dprofile options per: http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Running+the+Product+on+a+Preferred+Profile
and both components are configured as follows:

```
CarbonDB = wso2reg
User = wso2user
API = wso2API
Reg = wso2SharedRegistry (for governance and config).
```

When I create a new API on the Publisher and then publish to the gateway I see in the logs that it gets published:
INFO - API Initializing API: admin--CleanPhoneVerify:v1.0.0

But when I log into the Store on port 9447 (https://StorePubServer.domain.ext:9447/Store) I don't see the API.
However, when I log into the address (https://StorePubServer.domian.ext:9446/Store) I see it.

Question 1: Shouldn't the preferred profile start options prevent the Store from working on port 9446?
Question 2: Why don't I see the api on the Store running on port 9447 that I started with my -Dprofile option?

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1

At the moment profiles doesn't remove the web applications, ie Store and Publisher apps. They only remove features coming through Jars by eliminating those jars which are not related to the given profile.

Answer 2

Please enable clustering in Store and Publisher by setting to same clustering domain. For that do the below changes to both Store and Publisher.
1. Open AM_HOME/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml and locate clustering configuration.
2. Make clustering true

```
<clustering class="org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent"
                enable="true">
```

1. Set a clustering domain value. This should be same to both Store and Publisher.

   ```
    <parameter name="domain">storepub.domain</parameter>
   ```

   Restart the servers and try with a new API.

Comment: So clustering should be used...even if on the same server?

Comment: Also...if I can't remove the store when starting the publisher, does it make more sense to not seperate those components?